# How can i send gmail from my app on AWS EC2?

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, gmail

I Deployed my spring boot app and I'm trying to send a verification email and it returns `javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException`. on my locale machine everything works. I searched on forums and found that EC2 instances IPs are blocked by google also AWS SES has a problem, recipient mail should be verified on AWS. if somebody has experience with AWS please give me some advice.

Answer (score 0):

EC2 IPs are not blocked by google, that's not true, however, if AWS notices there is a high flow of emails on SMTP ports like 25,587.. then they throttle the ports, and you need to reach them to remove the throttle.

in your case `AuthenticationFailedException` this is not related to the case above, it's definitely related to the logins you are using.

You can use SendGrid as its free, SES is very excellent service, however you need to verify the domain not the email if you want to use it in production applications